# Sonar fails on Periodic Jobs (sometimes) but works on manually started jobs

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using sonar with jenkins. Jenkins works when a I run a build manually. The jobs fails 1 or 2 times in 3 excusions (fails randomly).

At lost many times in this problem. The project is composed by many modules.

Any idea ?

```
    logs :
    [JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode-view/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-view-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-service/codecode-service-publishing/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode-service-publishing/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-service-publishing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-service/codecode-service-publishing/target/codecode-service-publishing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.It.test/codecode-service-publishing/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-service-publishing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-service/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode-service/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-customer/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode-view-customer/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-view-customer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-customer/target/codecode-view-customer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.It.test/codecode-view-customer/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-view-customer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-service/codecode-service-notification/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode-service-codesms/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-service-codesms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-service/codecode-service-notification/target/codecode-service-codesms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.It.test/codecode-service-codesms/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-service-codesms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-service/codecode-service-exploitation/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode-service-exploitation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-service-exploitation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-service/codecode-service-exploitation/target/codecode-service-exploitation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.It.test/codecode-service-exploitation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-service-exploitation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-controller/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode-controller/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-controller-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-controller/target/codecode-controller-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.It.test/codecode-controller/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-controller-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-backoffice/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode-view-backoffice/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-view-backoffice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-backoffice/target/codecode-view-backoffice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to com.It.test/codecode-view-backoffice/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-view-backoffice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-service/codecode-service-api/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode-service-api/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-service-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-service/codecode-service-api/target/codecode-service-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.It.test/codecode-service-api/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-service-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-model/pom.xml to com.It.test/codecode-model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-model/target/codecode-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.It.test/codecode-model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/codecode-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
channel stopped
[Cobertura] Publishing Cobertura coverage report...
Publishing Cobertura coverage results...
Cobertura coverage report found.
[workspace] $ /usr/local/maven/bin/mvn -f /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/pom.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.6.91:9000 ******** ******** -Dmaven.repo.local=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/.repository
which: no javac in (/usr/local/maven/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] codeCode | Master
[INFO] codeCode | Model
[INFO] codeCode | View
[INFO] codeCode | View Customer
[INFO] codeCode | Service
[INFO] codeCode | Service API
[INFO] codeCode | Service SMS
[INFO] codeCode | View Backoffice
[INFO] codeCode | Controller
[INFO] codeCode | Service Exploitation
[INFO] codeCode | Service Publishing
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building codeCode | Master 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The following dependencies could not be resolved at this point of the build but seem to be part of the reactor:
[WARNING] o com.It.test:codecode-model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (compile)
[WARNING] Try running the build up to the lifecycle phase "package"
[WARNING] The following dependencies could not be resolved at this point of the build but seem to be part of the reactor:
[WARNING] o com.It.test:codecode-service-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (compile)
[WARNING] o com.It.test:codecode-model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (compile)
[WARNING] Try running the build up to the lifecycle phase "package"
[WARNING] The following dependencies could not be resolved at this point of the build but seem to be part of the reactor:
[WARNING] o com.It.test:codecode-service-codesms:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (compile)
[WARNING] o com.It.test:codecode-service-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (compile)
[WARNING] o com.It.test:codecode-model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (compile)
[WARNING] Try running the build up to the lifecycle phase "package"
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.2:sonar (default-cli) @ codecode ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 3.7.4
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 3.7.4
[INFO] [16:32:35.529] Load batch settings
[INFO] [16:32:35.921] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [16:32:35.951] Install plugins
[INFO] [16:32:37.172] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [16:32:37.197] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
[INFO] [16:32:41.244] Initializing Hibernate
[INFO] [16:32:49.388] Load project settings
[INFO] [16:32:49.441] Apply project exclusions
[INFO] [16:32:50.660] -------------  Scan codeCode | Model
[INFO] [16:32:50.673] Load module settings
[INFO] [16:32:52.393] Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
[INFO] [16:32:52.461] Excluded tests: 
[INFO] [16:32:52.466]   **/package-info.java
[INFO] [16:32:52.641] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [16:32:52.883] Compare to previous analysis (2014-07-28)
[INFO] [16:32:53.141] Compare over 30 days (2014-06-28, analysis of 2014-07-25 15:23:03.0)
[INFO] [16:32:53.265] Compare to previous version
[INFO] [16:32:53.778] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer...
[INFO] [16:32:53.821] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer done: 43 ms
[INFO] [16:32:53.827] Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-model
[INFO] [16:32:53.827] Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-model/target/sonar
[INFO] [16:32:53.827] Source dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-model/src/main/java
[INFO] [16:32:53.827] Binary dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-model/target/classes
[INFO] [16:32:53.829] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [16:32:53.868] Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO] [16:32:54.037] Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 169 ms
[INFO] [16:32:54.037] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [16:32:54.284] Java AST scan...
[INFO] [16:32:55.739] Java AST scan done: 1455 ms
[INFO] [16:32:55.761] Java bytecode scan...
[INFO] [16:32:55.987] Java bytecode scan done: 225 ms
[INFO] [16:32:56.047] Package design analysis...
[INFO] [16:32:56.123] Package design analysis done: 76 ms
[INFO] [16:32:56.288] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 2251 ms
[INFO] [16:32:56.289] Sensor SurefireSensor...
[INFO] [16:32:56.290] parsing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-model/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] [16:32:56.291] Sensor SurefireSensor done: 3 ms
[INFO] [16:32:56.291] Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO] [16:32:56.291] SonarEngine is used
[INFO] [16:32:56.293] Cross-project analysis disabled
[INFO] [16:32:56.640] Sensor CpdSensor done: 349 ms
[INFO] [16:32:56.640] Sensor CheckstyleSensor...
[INFO] [16:32:56.642] Execute Checkstyle 5.6...
[INFO] [16:32:56.687] Checkstyle configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-model/target/sonar/checkstyle.xml
[INFO] [16:33:01.043] Execute Checkstyle 5.6 done: 4401 ms
[INFO] [16:33:01.066] Sensor CheckstyleSensor done: 4426 ms
[INFO] [16:33:01.067] Sensor PmdSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:01.072] Execute PMD 4.3...
[INFO] [16:33:01.162] Java version: 1.7
[INFO] [16:33:01.465] PMD configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-model/target/sonar/pmd.xml
[INFO] [16:33:06.534] Execute PMD 4.3 done: 5462 ms
[INFO] [16:33:06.792] Sensor PmdSensor done: 5725 ms
[INFO] [16:33:06.792] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:06.842] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 50 ms
[INFO] [16:33:06.842] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:07.311] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 469 ms
[INFO] [16:33:07.313] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:07.412] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 99 ms
[INFO] [16:33:07.412] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:07.417] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 5 ms
[INFO] [16:33:07.417] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:07.449] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 32 ms
[INFO] [16:33:07.449] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [16:33:07.771] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 322 ms
[INFO] [16:33:07.771] Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:07.798] Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-model/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [16:33:08.286] No information about coverage per test.
[INFO] [16:33:08.286] Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 515 ms
[INFO] [16:33:09.853] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [16:33:14.013] -------------  Scan codeCode | View Customer
[INFO] [16:33:14.015] Load module settings
[INFO] [16:33:15.063] Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
[INFO] [16:33:15.077] Excluded tests: 
[INFO] [16:33:15.077]   **/package-info.java
[INFO] [16:33:15.179] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [16:33:15.376] Compare to previous analysis (2014-07-28)
[INFO] [16:33:15.477] Compare over 30 days (2014-06-28, analysis of 2014-07-25 15:23:03.0)
[INFO] [16:33:15.604] Compare to previous version
[INFO] [16:33:15.924] Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-customer
[INFO] [16:33:15.925] Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-customer/target/sonar
[INFO] [16:33:15.925] Binary dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-customer/target/classes
[INFO] [16:33:15.925] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [16:33:15.942] Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO] [16:33:15.942] Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:15.942] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:15.942] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:15.943] Sensor SurefireSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:15.943] parsing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-customer/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] [16:33:15.961] Sensor SurefireSensor done: 18 ms
[INFO] [16:33:15.962] Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:15.962] SonarEngine is used
[INFO] [16:33:15.962] Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:15.962] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:15.966] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 4 ms
[INFO] [16:33:15.969] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:16.918] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 949 ms
[INFO] [16:33:16.918] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:16.945] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 27 ms
[INFO] [16:33:16.945] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:16.958] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 13 ms
[INFO] [16:33:16.958] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:16.986] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 28 ms
[INFO] [16:33:16.987] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [16:33:17.000] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 13 ms
[INFO] [16:33:17.001] Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:17.001] Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-customer/target/jacoco.exec
[WARN] [16:33:17.007] Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
[INFO] [16:33:17.007] Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 6 ms
[INFO] [16:33:18.491] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [16:33:18.696] -------------  Scan codeCode | View Backoffice
[INFO] [16:33:18.698] Load module settings
[INFO] [16:33:19.484] Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
[INFO] [16:33:19.486] Excluded tests: 
[INFO] [16:33:19.494]   **/package-info.java
[INFO] [16:33:19.593] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [16:33:19.740] Compare to previous analysis (2014-07-28)
[INFO] [16:33:19.832] Compare over 30 days (2014-06-28, analysis of 2014-07-25 15:23:03.0)
[INFO] [16:33:19.917] Compare to previous version
[INFO] [16:33:20.472] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer...
[INFO] [16:33:20.472] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:20.473] Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-backoffice
[INFO] [16:33:20.473] Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-backoffice/target/sonar
[INFO] [16:33:20.473] Source dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-backoffice/src/main/java
[INFO] [16:33:20.473] Binary dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-backoffice/target/classes
[INFO] [16:33:20.473] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [16:33:20.522] Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO] [16:33:20.723] Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 201 ms
[INFO] [16:33:20.723] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:20.752] Java AST scan...
[INFO] [16:33:21.897] Java AST scan done: 1145 ms
[INFO] [16:33:21.937] Java bytecode scan...
[WARN] [16:33:24.179] Class 'com/It/test/codecode/service/api/NotificationService' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[INFO] [16:33:24.240] Java bytecode scan done: 2304 ms
[INFO] [16:33:24.245] Package design analysis...
[INFO] [16:33:24.317] Package design analysis done: 72 ms
[INFO] [16:33:24.423] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 3700 ms
[INFO] [16:33:24.424] Sensor SurefireSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:24.424] parsing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-backoffice/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] [16:33:24.424] Sensor SurefireSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:24.424] Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:24.425] SonarEngine is used
[INFO] [16:33:24.427] Cross-project analysis disabled
[INFO] [16:33:24.669] Sensor CpdSensor done: 245 ms
[INFO] [16:33:24.669] Sensor CheckstyleSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:24.669] Execute Checkstyle 5.6...
[INFO] [16:33:24.684] Checkstyle configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-backoffice/target/sonar/checkstyle.xml
[INFO] [16:33:27.528] Execute Checkstyle 5.6 done: 2859 ms
[INFO] [16:33:27.533] Sensor CheckstyleSensor done: 2864 ms
[INFO] [16:33:27.533] Sensor PmdSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:27.534] Execute PMD 4.3...
[INFO] [16:33:27.535] Java version: 1.6
[INFO] [16:33:27.561] PMD configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-backoffice/target/sonar/pmd.xml
[INFO] [16:33:30.868] Execute PMD 4.3 done: 3334 ms
[INFO] [16:33:30.872] Sensor PmdSensor done: 3339 ms
[INFO] [16:33:30.872] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:30.909] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 37 ms
[INFO] [16:33:30.909] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:31.126] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 217 ms
[INFO] [16:33:31.127] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:31.151] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 23 ms
[INFO] [16:33:31.151] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:31.156] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 5 ms
[INFO] [16:33:31.156] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:31.230] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 74 ms
[INFO] [16:33:31.231] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [16:33:34.103] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 2872 ms
[INFO] [16:33:34.103] Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:34.118] Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/codecode-view-backoffice/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [16:33:34.402] No information about coverage per test.
[INFO] [16:33:34.402] Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 299 ms
[INFO] [16:33:35.030] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [16:33:36.464] -------------  Scan codeCode | View
[INFO] [16:33:36.466] Load module settings
[INFO] [16:33:37.282] Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
[INFO] [16:33:37.286] Excluded tests: 
[INFO] [16:33:37.290]   **/package-info.java
[INFO] [16:33:37.447] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [16:33:37.543] Compare to previous analysis (2014-07-28)
[INFO] [16:33:37.607] Compare over 30 days (2014-06-28, analysis of 2014-07-25 15:23:03.0)
[INFO] [16:33:37.624] Compare to previous version
[INFO] [16:33:37.714] Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view
[INFO] [16:33:37.714] Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/target/sonar
[INFO] [16:33:37.714] Binary dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/target/classes
[INFO] [16:33:37.715] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [16:33:37.717] Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO] [16:33:37.718] Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 1 ms
[INFO] [16:33:37.718] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:37.718] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:37.718] Sensor SurefireSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:37.718] parsing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-view/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] [16:33:37.718] Sensor SurefireSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:37.719] Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:37.719] SonarEngine is used
[INFO] [16:33:37.719] Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:37.719] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:37.723] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 4 ms
[INFO] [16:33:37.723] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:38.089] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 366 ms
[INFO] [16:33:38.093] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:38.099] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 6 ms
[INFO] [16:33:38.099] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:38.106] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 7 ms
[INFO] [16:33:38.106] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:38.113] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 7 ms
[INFO] [16:33:38.113] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [16:33:38.135] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 22 ms
[INFO] [16:33:38.136] Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:38.136] Project coverage is set to 0% since there is no directories with classes.
[INFO] [16:33:38.136] Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:38.509] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [16:33:38.830] -------------  Scan codeCode | Controller
[INFO] [16:33:38.832] Load module settings
[INFO] [16:33:39.370] Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
[INFO] [16:33:39.372] Excluded tests: 
[INFO] [16:33:39.372]   **/package-info.java
[INFO] [16:33:39.401] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [16:33:39.461] Compare to previous analysis (2014-07-28)
[INFO] [16:33:39.468] Compare over 30 days (2014-06-28, analysis of 2014-07-25 15:23:03.0)
[INFO] [16:33:39.477] Compare to previous version
[INFO] [16:33:39.558] Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-controller
[INFO] [16:33:39.560] Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-controller/target/sonar
[INFO] [16:33:39.560] Binary dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-controller/target/classes
[INFO] [16:33:39.560] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [16:33:39.563] Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO] [16:33:39.563] Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:39.564] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:39.564] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:39.567] Sensor SurefireSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:39.567] parsing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/codeCodes/workspace/codecode-controller/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] [16:33:39.568] Sensor SurefireSensor done: 1 ms
[INFO] [16:33:39.568] Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:39.568] SonarEngine is used
[INFO] [16:33:39.568] Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:33:39.569] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:39.610] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 41 ms
[INFO] [16:33:39.610] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [16:33:40.952] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 1169 ms
[INFO] [16:33:41.562] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you add the console's content of your Jenkins Job ?

Comment: cleaning the workspace solves the problem